# Implementing useContext issue. useState value not updating when being called

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-context

I have a react native application and I am currently implementing a simple version of `useContext` to test it and get familiar with it in order to use it efficiently.

Right now I am creating a `useContext` object called `FilterSortContext` and that looks like this:

`FilterSortContext.js`:

```
import { createContext } from "react";

export const FilterSortContext = createContext(null)
```

Now what I want to do is pass in all of the different states that I will need and be changing throughout the application into the `useContext` to update quickly.

I currently have every `state` and `setState` passed into the value. I also have `useEffect` function that I want to trigger when the state changes to make sure it is working correctly

`HomeScreen.js`:

```
import React, { useState, createContext, useEffect} from 'react'
import {View, Text, StyleSheet} from 'react-native'

import { FilterSortContext } from '../context/FilterSortContext';

import SearchAndFilterComponent from '../components/HomeScreen/SearchAndFilterComponent';

const HomeScreen = () => {
  const [currentSearch, setCurrentSeach] = useState('')
  const [activeSearch, setActiveSearch] = useState('')
  const [sort, setSort] = useState('Homes_for_You')
  const [filter, sestFilter] = useState()
  const [results, setResults] = useState([])
  const [resultCounter, setResultCounter] = useState(0)
  const [page, setPage] = useState(1)
  const [totalPages, setTotalPages] = useState(0)
  const [resultView, setResultView] = useState('List')

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(currentSearch)
  }, [currentSearch])


  return (
    <View style={styles.screen}>
      <FilterSortContext.Provider value={{currentSearch, setCurrentSeach, activeSearch, setActiveSearch,
                                          sort, setSort, filter, sestFilter, results, setResults,
                                          resultCounter, setResultCounter, page, setPage, totalPages, setTotalPages,
                                          resultView, setResultView}}>
        <SearchAndFilterComponent/>
      </FilterSortContext.Provider>
      <View style={styles.fullSplit}></View>
    </View>
  )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  fullSplit: {
    width: '100%',
    height: 2,
    backgroundColor: 'black'
  }
})

export default HomeScreen
```

This is 1 of the files that I will be updating the variables with:

```
import React, { useState, useContext } from 'react'
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, TextInput, Dimensions } from 'react-native'

import { Feather } from '@expo/vector-icons'

import { FilterSortContext } from '../../context/FilterSortContext'

const searchInputWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width - 165

const SearchAndFilterComponent = () => {
  const {currentSearch, setCurrentSearch} = useContext(FilterSortContext)

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.bar}> 
        <View style={styles.searchContainer}>
          <View style={styles.search}>
            <View style={styles.searchIconContainer}>
              <Feather style={styles.searchIcon} name='search' color={'#273be2'} size={24} />
            </View>
            <View style={styles.searchInputContainer}>
              <TextInput style={[styles.searchInput, {width: searchInputWidth}]} 
                value={currentSearch} 
                onChange={setCurrentSearch}  
                placeholder={'Search City or Address...'}/>
            </View>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.navigationContainer}>
            <Feather name='navigation' color={'#273be2'} size={24} />
          </View>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.splitter}></View>
        <View style={styles.mapContainer}>
          <Feather style={styles.buttonIcon} name='map' color={'#273be2'} size={24} />
          <Text style={styles.text}>Map</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.verticalSplitter}></View>
    </View>
  )
}
```

I want the input field to update `state` dynamically.

SIDE QUESTIONS?

Can I call `useContext` in any screen and call `useContext(FilterSortContext)` even though the value is set in `HomeScreen` or should I wrap the entire App functions in the App.js file?

Comment: You missed a letter when you entered 'setCurrentSeach' to the 'value' prop of the context provider. Fix it to 'setCurrentSearch'. For the second question: you can call 'useContext' in any child component of a context provider.

Comment: So if I want to call ```useContext``` it anywhere in the application, I have to add it to the root ```App.js``` file.  Do you know If I can create a file names like ```FIlterSortState.js``` and add all the states i need and then import that or should I just add all the state in their respoective components. Would it be smart to just use 1 large context for the entire application?? @AlonBarenboim